# IzPack Generating installer.log without Uninstaller Folder

Tags: java, izpack

I have an IzPack 5.0 installation and have switched off the uninstaller function. However, I would like to keep the install.log. Unfortunately, I can only generate the install.log if the function for the uninstaller is also activated. Is there another way to create the install.log?

....
        
 
  
     .....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.